# How to check logs of certain pod by just using deployment name alone

Tags: kubernetes

**Problem Statement**

I have a Kubernetes cluster with many pods running in a particular namespace. I want to read the logs of a particular pod using Python with the Paramiko SSH client.

I have pods running below

```
kubectl get pods -n <myNameSpace>
```

The result of the above command will look like

```
service1-8457bd9899-4jdzz
service2-765b497fbf-2w82j
```

Here is my Python code, I know the deployment names such as service1, service2 etc

I want to read the logs using those names alone like

```
kubectl logs service1* -n <myNameSpace> -f --tail 100
```

But the above command won't work because that regular expression won't work.

**My Solution**

I am running two commands one to get the full pod name and the other to check the logs using that full name

```
 ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(f'kubectl get pods -n namespace1 |grep service1')
 pod_name_service1 = ssh_stdout.read().decode("utf-8").split(' ')[0]
 ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(
                f'kubectl logs {pod_name_service1} -n edge -f --tail 100')
 service1_logs = ssh_stdout.read().decode("utf-8")
```

**Question**

How to use just the service depolyment name alone (without replicaset name + random 5-digit alphanumeric) to retrieve logs? Is there any other way exist for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only one replica, or if you don't care which replica you get, you can directly use the Deployment name on the command line

```bash
kubectl logs -n my-namespace deployment/service1 --tail 100 -f
```

Note that this is one of a couple of commands that actually works on a specific Pod, even though you can use a `deployment/name` syntax (other object types will work too).  If the specific Pod that this attaches to exits then the `kubectl logs` command will stop too, even if other replicas remain running uninterrupted.

(I would also strongly suggest fixing the shell-injection vulnerability in your code.  Consider using a Kubernetes SDK over executing `kubectl` commands, maybe port-forwarding the Kubernetes API endpoint over the ssh connection if needed.)

Answer (score 0):

this might be what might get you there more easily. (compared to regex, that is.)

```
kubectl logs -l app=yourappname
```

[docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs)

Comment: This is not working. Thanks for the suggestion by the way